# HTML/CSS: Text overlay on a background image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position some text on a background image. I am having trouble bringing the text down on to the "screen area" of the mobile image.

I used margin-top on *.text-content*, but it is pushing down the complete background image.

Currently working on FF29, but I would like this to work on all modern browsers.

Here is the link to my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sga/sHhfy/2/.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="mainPage">
        <div class="main-content">
            <div class="text-content">
                <div class="text-body">Hello World!</div>
                <div class="text-body">Hello World!</div>
                <div class="text-body">Hello World!</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.mainPage {
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.main-content {
    background: yellow url('http://s15.postimg.org/mrlg0biuz/mobile.png')
        no-repeat center;
    width: 600px;
    height: 450px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.text-content {
    text-align: center;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use z-index:-1 for image background in the css and z-index:1 for your other div content. That way your image will be on the background and it won't affect other views/divs/items.

Comment: Yep, you need to give the .text-content position: absolute; to free-float it over the top of the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use padding-top on .text-content instead of margin-top:

```
.text-content {
    text-align: center;
    color:#fff;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4fffd/)